# Upgrade to opencv-python 4.7 causes import error

Tags: python, macos, opencv

While working on a project that uses the opencv-python module, I ended up updating it to version 4.7.0.68 from 4.6.0.66. The next time I ran my program it failed with an import error:
`ImportError: dlopen(path/to/my/virtualenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: _VTRegisterSupplementalVideoDecoderIfAvailable`

After downgrading opencv-python back to 4.6.0.66 the import error went away and things went back to running without error.

Given that OpenCV 4.7 was released fairly recently and from what I can tell `_VTRegisterSupplementalVideoDecoderIfAvailable` is a function of macOS I'm guessing that this is some sort of compatibility bug in the new version of opencv-python. On the machine where the error occurred I'm running macOS Catalina (10.15.7).

To isolate that the issue is strictly related to opencv-python, I created a clean environment, installed opencv-python 4.7 and attempted to run a script with the single line `import cv2`. This failed with the same error.

[This issue](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/discussions/5461?sort=new?sort=new#discussioncomment-4623416) in an unrelated project hints that it's possible upgrading my OS may be needed.

I can live with downgrading to 4.6 but curious to know if there's an alternative solution to fix this import error.

Comment: I don't see any issues mentioning this (opencv/opencv, opencv/opencv_contrib, opencv/opencv-python repos), but also not any source code of OpenCV, which is curious. perhaps submit an issue. would be great if you (or anyone else) could reproduce this, or not reproduce this, on the same or similar operating system version

Comment: Just a thought, but did you upgrade your import packages to be compatible?

Comment: I also spent a good deal of time looking around to see if there were any issues already open about this elsewhere. The only one I could find was [this one in an unrelated project](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/discussions/5461?sort=new?sort=new#discussioncomment-4591464) -- though it sounds pretty much identical.

Comment: @fmw42, not sure exactly what you mean by "upgrading my import packages". I was able to recreate the problem by creating a clean project with a fresh environment, and installed opencv-python 4.7. This failed when run with the same error.

Comment: What packages do you import in your python script?  Are they compatible with your upgraded Python.

Comment: Definitely considered that it could be other packages causing issues so I tested by recreating the problem in a clean environment with the only installed package being opencv-python 4.7. Attempting to run a script with only the single line of `import cv2` fails with the same error.

Answer (score 7):

I got this problem too.
The macOS Catalina 10.15.7 system seems too old for the new opencv package

```
pip3 install opencv-python==4.6.0.66
```